# NSMutableDictionary as DataSource for UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a NSMutabledictionary stored in nsuserdefaults that looks like this: (key on left, value on right)

```
{
"3/2/14, 12:17:08 PM Central Standard Time" = 220;
"3/2/14, 12:37:28 PM Central Standard Time" = 220;
}
```

I want to display these values in a UITableView as

```
3/2/14  220
```

Or similar, with date on left, weight on right.

How do I load the cell in the UITableView with this information?

Comment: You load this information like every other information by assigning an object to a cell at a given index path in the UTableView delegate. You can setup your own UITableViewCell layout subclass and just the display to your needs or use one of Apple's pre-defined cell designs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [NSUserDefaults class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/objectForKey:) regarding `objectForKey`:

> > The returned object is immutable, even if the value you originally set was mutable.

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16876138/mutable-objects-inside-nsuserdefaults) for a relevant discussion on this topic.

That being said, you can access the keys of an `NSDictionary` with its `allKeys` property and enumerate the content of your dictionary in a key-value manner like this:

```
for (id key in dictionary.allKeys) {
    value = dictionary[key];
}
```

However, you should not use a mutable collection (that is, `NSMutableDictionary`) as data source since there is a potential risk for the data to change (remember, it is mutable) after it has been handed to the tableview. Instead, create an `NSDictionary` with the contents of your `NSMutableDictionary`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a dictionary as a data source for a table view. A table view is an ordered presentation. A dictionary is an unordered collection. There is nothing keeping the objects in the dictionary in any particular order.

An NSArray is a good choice as the model for a table view data source. You can certainly use an array of dictionaries if that works.

You could also query the dictionary for it's keys using the allKeys method, and then save the resulting array, and fetch the entries in your dictionary using indexes from your allKeys array.